# mySQL: Removing a regex substring

Tags: mysql, regex, string

I have urls stored in my database table in the following format

`http://domain.com/images/4/8/48bafb746bb7baa695481574afc345eb61af8d0a.jpg`, and `http://domain.com/images/0/f/0f602869e208139d2da67867359fb7cf092eb02b.jpg.jpg`

I want to change the directory the file are stored in and reflect this change in the DB. Something like the following.

`http://domain.com/images/48bafb746bb7baa695481574afc345eb61af8d0a.jpg`, and `http://domain.com/images/0f602869e208139d2da67867359fb7cf092eb02b.jpg.jpg`

I simply want to move all images up two directories. How can I remove the top two directories from the string?

Comment: mysql regexes can only match. they cannot replace or alter. You'd need to use standard mysql string operations for the changes, or do the search/replace in client-side code.

Comment: Are the directory names always exactly one character as you have above? (that makes string ops a little easier)

Comment: FYI, you're moving them _up_ two directories, not down.

Comment: You don't need regexp for this, it looks like you should be able to do it with `substring_index`.

Comment: [`(?:[^\/]+\/){2}([^\/]+)$`](http://regex101.com/r/nN4uN9), be careful if there are not more than 2 directories and you use this.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just write a simple script to do this? That may give you more control in making sure you are updating only the records you are targeting.  If however all image URL's are in same format (i.e. two directories deep), than an update based on using `substring_index` would be a suitable approach.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Yes they are.

Comment: @MikeBrant, I'm currently considering a mysqldump and using a text editor to make the change.

Comment: @andre That sounds painful.  How many rows are you talking about?

Comment: @MikeBrant its only 800 at the moment. I was thinking of using a find and replace not manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try with substring_index

```
 select concat('http://domain.com/images/', substring_index('http://domain.com/images/4/8/48bafb746bb7baa695481574afc345eb61af8d0a.jpg','/',-1))
```

to edit your records you could do something like this:

```
 update yourtable set yourcoulmnpath= concat('http://domain.com/images/', substring_index(yourcoulmnpath,'/',-1))
```

Comment: That works like i want it too. I'll try to use this to change every entry. Any chance you know how to write a select statement or function to take advantage of this?

Comment: I edited my answer to show you how you could update your records

Comment: Nice and efficient neiha :) +1